# Proof of expected value of positive random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The below is an answer I found from the following question:

I didn't understand why the double integral switch worked that way and the comment did not clear things up for me. I'm hoping someone could provide an alternative explanation. Thanks!

Answer:

"

Assuming we have a continuous random variable with an existant probability density function $f_Y$.

$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \Pr(Y \geqslant y) \operatorname d y
& =
\int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty f_Y(z)\operatorname d z\operatorname d y 
\\[1ex] & =
\int_0^\infty \int_0^z f_Y(z)\operatorname d y\operatorname d z 
\\[1ex] & =
\int_0^\infty f_Y(z)\int_0^z 1\operatorname d y\;\operatorname d z 
\\[1ex] & =
\int_0^\infty z f_Y(z)\operatorname d z 
\\[1ex] & =
\mathsf E[Y] 
\end{align}$

"

Comment: I tried to edit the link to make it work, but I don't think the link works correctly

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because you are integrating over the region 
\begin{align}\{ (z,y) : y\in(0,\infty), z\in(y,\infty) \} &= \{ (z,y) : y\in(0,\infty), z\in(0,\infty), y<z \}\\ & = \{ (z,y) : y\in(0,z), z\in(0,\infty) \}  \end{align}
So if we're integrating in $y$ first, $y<z$ means we should only integrate up to $z$

Comment: I'm picturing z and y forming a 2 dimensional plane and each point (z,y) a point in that plane. Then we are summing the height of infinitesimally small rectangles represented at each of these points correct?  Its clear that we don't want to include volume from boxes that are above the points (z,y) for z $\lt$ y, as the points along the z axis start at y. Am i on the right track? I think this explains how u get ur first equality, but I'm sure about the last one

Comment: It just seems like the last equality would contain points that are not in the original set as it would contain the point (y-1,y) but in the original set z must be in the interval (y,$\infty$). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, now do the same picture, but instead of very flat, wide rectangles, use very thin, tall rectangles. This is the second equality. Or algebraically, just note that the conditions
$$ y \in (0,\infty) , y < z$$
combine into $$ 0 <y   <z$$

Comment: The point $(y_0-1,y_0)$ is not in this set, because  we need $ y \in (0,z)$, and $y_0 \notin (0,y_0 - 1)$ (i.e. $y_0 \not< y_0 - 1$)  @H_1317

Comment: Thanks! that turned out to be very simple, i think i was having difficulty seeing a statement that had on the RHS of the colon with the variables working off of each other. ie once u pick a z coordinate, ur possible y choices are limited. I feel like most often statements on the RHS are more disjoint. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :)